# Relationship between special RSA modulus and quadratic residue in CL (Camenisch-Lysyanskaya) signature

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-arithmetic, cryptography, quadratic-residues

I'm studying the CL(Camenisch-Lysyanskaya) signature ("A signature scheme with efficient protocol proposed by Camenisch-Lysyanskaya").

However, I cannot understand the relationship between special RSA modulus and quadratic residue.

[image]

What is relationship between Special RSA modulus and quadratic residue?

and please recommend the references about special rsa modulus.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is this the same question from crypto.